# What is used instead of nolam and malam? (First person singular, future tense)

Tags: irregular-words

The future first person singulars of nolo (I will not want) and malo (I will prefer) are apparently not found. In other words, *nolam* and *malam* (and *males*) are not found according to the Cambridge Grammar by Jones and Sidwell (although I have not found this claim in other grammars).

If this is the case, and these forms are not found, what is used instead?

Comment: I don't see any instances in the corpus, but I have to wonder if this is an actual rule or just an accidental gap.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that the practice was to use the future perfect. So, for example,

Si quis quaesiverit unde sciam, primum, ***si noluero, non respondebo***. (Seneca the Younger)

(If anyone should ask for the source of my information, in the first place, if I do not wish to, I will not answer.)

So, we can see that the future perfect of *nolo* is correlated with the simple future of *respondeo*. I found a similar example using *maluero*.

Comment: The Seneca example is no “slam-dunk” case, as this can be simply a regular use of the future perfect, seeing that the not-wanting is a precondition to not-doing. If this seems ridiculous to you, then compare [Cic. Mil. 93](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0011%3Atext%3DMil.%3Asection%3D93): *si mihi bona re publica frui non licuerit, at carebo mala*.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel That is true, it may be happenstance. I could not find any cases where the author was saying "I will prefer" in the simple future.

Answer (score 3):

The only place where I have found the claim that *nolam* and *malam* are not used are older (19<sup>th</sup> century) German grammars such as [this one](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Lateinische_Grammatik_f%C3%BCr_Gymnasien/ugWd5vH3HzgC?hl=de&gbpv=1&pg=PA189&printsec=frontcover). These invariably claim that ***nolim*** and ***malim*** are used instead. In newer grammars this idea seems to have disappeared, and Jones & Sidwell may be an outlier here.

The belief that this is so may be grounded in locis like this from Plautus ([Amphitruo 1, 1](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0030%3Aact%3D1%3Ascene%3D1)):

> Ubi ego Sosia nolim esse, tu esto sane Sosia.

There would be no good reason to expect the subjunctive here, so it has been interpreted as future. Of course, you can explain away any irregularity in Plautus with some imagination, and so it has been done in this case by [claiming](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Wissenschaftliche_Abhandlung/vqZEAQAAIAAJ?hl=de&gbpv=1&pg=PA3&printsec=frontcover) that this is in fact an unusual alternative future form *nolem* ([Alfred Fleckeisen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Wilhelm_Alfred_Fleckeisen)).

Interestingly, *volam* is attested. If, in composition, I were to find myself in need of the first person singular future form, I would simply use *nolam* and *malam*.

Answer (score 2):

According to Richard Prior and Joseph Wohlberg, *501 Latin Verbs*, The future 1p. singular of *nolo* is what you said, *nolam*.

But I couldn't find any examples of *nolam* the verb (just Nola, the proper noun) at [PHI](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=nolam).

The same with *malam*. Prior and Wohlberg agree with you, but I don't see it clearly (to me) used as a verb in PHI.

As for alternatives, that would depend on what exactly you are trying to say. The subjunctive might work, or the present with a future infinitive.

After all, if your present preference is the same as your future preference, then a present verb should do. And if your future preference will not be the same as your present one, then it sounds like the sort of hypothetical preference that subjunctive forms were made for.